# Display tweets between two dates

Tags: javascript, twitter

I need to display tweets between two dates. Right now , my block of code works but displays all the tweets.

This is the code i'm using:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/culturegames" data-widget-id="342255825936601088" width="550" height="600">Tweets de @culturegames</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the [`twitter-timeline` api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) which doesn't have a date feature, but it does have the `since_id` option - if you can update your html dynamically then you can set it to show tweets since a tweet at a particular time.

Alternatively you can use the [`twitter-search` api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) which does have `until` - maybe with something like

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@culturegames&until=2013-01-01
```